# Socket python can't send information to the server "client.send(name)"

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, server, client

I'm working on a game project with tkinter and Python 3.7 and i can't send the name of the player that i'm typing to the server.

Server

```
server = None
HOST_ADDR = "192.168.1.13"
HOST_PORT = 5555
client_name = ""
clients = []
clients_names = []
player_data = []

def start_server():
    global server, HOST_ADDR, HOST_PORT # code is fine without this
    btnStart.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    btnStop.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("socket.AF_INET")
    print("socket.SOCK_STREAM")

    server.bind((HOST_ADDR, HOST_PORT))
    server.listen(5)  # server is listening for client connection

    threading._start_new_thread(accept_clients, (server, " "))

    lblHost["text"] = "Address: " + HOST_ADDR
    lblPort["text"] = "Port: " + str(HOST_PORT)

def accept_clients(the_server, y):
    while True:
        if len(clients) < 2:
            client, addr = the_server.accept()
            clients.append(client)

            # use a thread so as not to clog the gui thread
            threading._start_new_thread(send_receive_client_message, (client, addr))
```

Client.py

```
client = None
HOST_ADDR = "192.168.1.13"
HOST_PORT = 5555

def connect():
    global your_details
    if len(ent_name.get()) < 1:
        tk.messagebox.showerror(title="ERROR!!!", message="You MUST enter your first name <e.g. John>")
    else:
        your_details["name"] = ent_name.get()
        connect_to_server(ent_name.get())

def connect_to_server(name):
    global client, HOST_PORT, HOST_ADDR
    try:
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect((HOST_ADDR, HOST_PORT))
        print('test') # OK, i can receive the print
        client.send(name) 
        print('test') # can't receive the print
        threading._start_new_thread(receive_message_from_server, (client, "m"))
        top_welcome_frame.pack_forget()
        top_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        window_main.title("Tic-Tac-Toe Client - " + name)
    except Exception as e:
        tk.messagebox.showerror(title="ERROR!!!", message="Cannot connect to host: " + HOST_ADDR + " on port: " + str(
            HOST_PORT) + " Server may be Unavailable. Try again later")
```

Each time i enter a name, it doesn't send the name that i typed `client.send(name)` and it goes in the else.
If someone can help me with that.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: The one that you can see at the end of my client , the message box

Comment: No, what is the original exception?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I have this button 
```btn_connect = tk.Button(top_welcome_frame, text="Connect", command=lambda : connect())```
and the function connect```def connect():
    global your_details
    if len(ent_name.get()) < 1:
        tk.messagebox.showerror(title="ERROR!!!", message="You MUST enter your first name <e.g. John>")
    else:
        your_details["name"] = ent_name.get()
        connect_to_server(ent_name.get())```

Comment: i did a ```print('test')``` inside ```def connect_to_the_server``` , it doesn't go below ```client.send(name)```